# Nesting loops (Threads) in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, nested-loops

As my title states, i need to nest for loops (i am not sure if nesting is the right word i am looking for, but i need one for loop, inside the other)

The current code i have is

```
public class Main {
    private static String[] passwords = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four"};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int threadds = 10;
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadds];
        for (int j = 0; j < passwords.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < passwords.length; i++) {
                ClaimSnipe NS = new ClaimSnipe();
                NS.password = String.valueOf(i);
                NS.i = i;
                NS.DropTome = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;
                Thread t = new Thread(NS);
                threads[i] = t;
                threads[i].setName(String.valueOf(i + 1));
                NS.ThreadName = String.valueOf(threads[i].getName());
                threads[i].start();
            }
        }

    }
}

class ClaimSnipe implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean exit = false;

    public String ThreadName;
    public String password;
    public int i;

    public long DropTome;

    public void stop() {
        exit = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long unixTimern = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (unixTimern < (DropTome) - 1000) {
            unixTimern = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread = " + ThreadName + "; i = " + i);
        stop();
    }
}
```

The result it gives is

```
Thread = 0; i = 0
Thread = 0; i = 1
Thread = 0; i = 2
Thread = 0; i = 3
Thread = 0; i = 4
Thread = 1; i = 0
Thread = 1; i = 1
Thread = 1; i = 2
Thread = 1; i = 3
Thread = 1; i = 4
Thread = 2; i = 0
Thread = 2; i = 1
Thread = 2; i = 2
Thread = 2; i = 3
Thread = 2; i = 4
Thread = 3; i = 0
Thread = 3; i = 1
Thread = 3; i = 2
Thread = 3; i = 3
Thread = 3; i = 4
Thread = 4; i = 0
Thread = 4; i = 1
Thread = 4; i = 2
Thread = 4; i = 3
Thread = 4; i = 4

Process finished with exit code 0

^^^ What i want

-----------------------------------------------------

Thread = 1; i = 0
Thread = 2; i = 1
Thread = 3; i = 2
Thread = 4; i = 3
Thread = 5; i = 4
Thread = 1; i = 0
Thread = 2; i = 1
Thread = 3; i = 2
Thread = 4; i = 3
Thread = 5; i = 4
Thread = 1; i = 0
Thread = 2; i = 1
Thread = 3; i = 2
Thread = 4; i = 3
Thread = 5; i = 4
Thread = 1; i = 0
Thread = 2; i = 1
Thread = 3; i = 2
Thread = 4; i = 3
Thread = 5; i = 4
Thread = 1; i = 0
Thread = 2; i = 1
Thread = 4; i = 3
Thread = 5; i = 4
Thread = 3; i = 2



Process finished with exit code 1

^^^ What i get...
Thread = 0; i = 0
Thread = 0; i = 1
Thread = 0; i = 2
Thread = 0; i = 3
Thread = 0; i = 4
Thread = 1; i = 0
Thread = 1; i = 1
Thread = 1; i = 2
Thread = 1; i = 3
Thread = 1; i = 4
Thread = 2; i = 0
Thread = 2; i = 1
Thread = 2; i = 2
Thread = 2; i = 3
Thread = 2; i = 4
Thread = 3; i = 0
Thread = 3; i = 1
Thread = 3; i = 2
Thread = 3; i = 3
Thread = 3; i = 4
Thread = 4; i = 0
Thread = 4; i = 1
Thread = 4; i = 2
Thread = 4; i = 3
Thread = 4; i = 4

Process finished with exit code 0

^^^ What i want

-----------------------------------------------------

Thread = 1; i = 0
Thread = 2; i = 1
Thread = 3; i = 2
Thread = 4; i = 3
Thread = 5; i = 4
Thread = 1; i = 0
Thread = 2; i = 1
Thread = 3; i = 2
Thread = 4; i = 3
Thread = 5; i = 4
Thread = 1; i = 0
Thread = 2; i = 1
Thread = 3; i = 2
Thread = 4; i = 3
Thread = 5; i = 4
Thread = 1; i = 0
Thread = 2; i = 1
Thread = 3; i = 2
Thread = 4; i = 3
Thread = 5; i = 4
Thread = 1; i = 0
Thread = 2; i = 1
Thread = 4; i = 3
Thread = 5; i = 4
Thread = 3; i = 2



Process finished with exit code 1

^^^ What i get...
```

I have tried changing where i call the ClaimSnipe NS but all that did was make it so only one thread was used

Comment: Are you saying that you want the threads to run according to a particular schedule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **line** **14** `threads[i].setName(String.valueOf(i + 1));`

- firstly adds 1 to your for loop counter variable and refers to the loop counter variable of your ***INNER FOR*** loop.

should be:

`threads[i].setName(String.valueOf(j));`

- which refers to loop counter variable of your ***OUTER FOR*** loop and also does not increase it by 1.

This change will align your existing code to get your desired output. I hope this does the trick for you.

Comment: FYI, `String.valueOf(i + 1)` does **not** change the value of `i`

Comment: Apologies for using the word "increment". Mistake on my part. Not what I meant. Corrected.